# If I delete pre-installed Windows 8.1, is it lost forever?

Tags: windows-8.1, operating-systems, license, product-key, license-key

There's this Asus X200MA with fixed 2GB RAM and pre-installed Windows 8.1 .
2GB RAM + Windows combination makes a sad computer and a frustrated user.

So I want to install Elementary OS Freya on it. I wanted to make it dual boot, but the Windows is UEFI installed and the ASUS bios is strange and it's all a mess, plus the user (gf) does really not need any functionality that would rule single-boot-eOS out.

But one never knows - if she will need the Windows or if the computer is to be sold, maybe I'll want to install the Windows back.

I read somewhere that the product key is burned in the motherboard and will be automatically loaded when I start installation. Is that true? Or is there any other way to hold onto the Windows licence, when I delete reformat the whole hard drive?

Comment: As the license key is held in BIOS then you could, in theory, install Windows 8.1 (just so long as the versions match) using any media. Be careful, though, if the Windows 8.1 key is OEM then you may struggle re-activating. Ideally you should use the Asus' recovery media creation tool. It should allow you to create a set of DVDs, Blurays or a USB disk that contains all the factory restore data on so that you can rebuild the machine if necessary. Anyone buying a new PC should do this the very first time they ever use their device. What would happen if the HDD died out of warranty?

Comment: Thanks @Big Chris. Is it not enough to make a partition image of Recovery (900MB), Restore(20GB), maybe the first boot partition (100MB) ? Which ones would I need?

Comment: Asus offer the ability to create a recovery drive... a 16GB USB is required: this forum may help http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/5132-recovery-drive-create-usb-flash-drive-windows-8-a.html

Comment: That will work even if I delete all the partitions, including recovery, restore etc.? 
EDIT: Oh I see. recovery is copied to the flash drive. I don't want to waste a flash drive though, will try to just create an image of it.

Comment: If you have an external USB hard disk (with plenty of space) then you could use a LiveCD for CloneZilla (with UEFI support) that will allow you to take a sector-by-secotr copy of your hard disk - this will take all data and all partitions as they are...

Comment: That would be 150GB wasted and I do not have a hard drive with 150GB to waste just in case.

Comment: You're limiting yourself to not very many options... if you take just the bare minimum partitions then you will need to restore the partitions - with the right MBR/GPT tables etc. because the "one button restore" relies on knowing where the partitions are... a solution such as CloneZilla will only take the data being used... it creates a record of the disk structure and then takes only the sectors in use - it won't just create a single image of the hard disk total size - that's rather inefficient! Well, it CAN take an entire disk, but, by default, it doesn't. ideally just make the recovery USB

Comment: Sure, I'll make the recovery USB. But then I'll make an image of the USB and save it to HDD, so I can continue using the USB normally. When I need, I clone the USB image back to the USB and restore.

Just one question - yes/no. In case of 'yes', please post first comment as an answer and I'll accept it:
**A recovery USB is sufficient to install functional W8.1 on a completely empty, even new HDD in a computer it was created on. Yes, no?**
Also, many thanks.

Comment: That's the whole point of making the recovery disk :) It'll put everything back on to (yes, even) an empty HDD. You must choose to copy the recovery partition data to the USB - there is a tick box on the Asus recovery creator!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the Asus recovery USB - you'll need a fairly hefty memory stick due to the recovery data size.

Ideally you should use the OEM's pre-created recovery media/process to restore an OEM machine such as from Asus. Modern computers you can make DVD/BluRay/USB recovery media. USB is more convenient. Using the OEM recovery will then guarantee that the Windows activation will function as the manufacturer intended.

The USB can then be used to boot your computer and completely restore the HDD to factory settings. This would also work if you plugged in a blank HDD or if the original laptop HDD failed. Making the recovery media yourself will save you a hefty bill from Asus to buy their pre-fabricated disks which you would have to order and wait to be delivered. Making your own saves a lot of time and hassle!

You could then make a DD of the memory stick in Linux to backup the USB which would then allow you to re-use the USB and duplicate the USB in the event it fails.